# Finite fundamental groups of 3-dimensional Calabi-Yau manifolds

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, ag.algebraic-geometry, calabi-yau

**Question.** Is there an example of a compact $3$-dimensional Calabi-Yau manifold with finite fundamental group $G$ that does not admit a free action on $S^3$?

This question is motivated by the following: it is known that many simply-connected Clabi-Yau 3-folds admit a singular Lagrangian torus fibration over $S^3$. I don't know if there are exceptions. On the other hand, if $\pi_1$ is finite and we still have a lagrangean torus fibration, one can expect that the base is a lens space. But in this case probably $\pi_1$ of the CY-manifold will be equal to $\pi_1$ of the base.

**PS.** As Tony Pantev explains, the answer to this question is YES -- there are such examples. On the other hand, if we assume that a finite group $G$ is acting freely on a CY 3-manifold preserving  the volume form and preserving a Lagrangian torus fibration, this should impose some very strong restrictions on $G$. I wonder if anyone bothered to work out what is the restriction :).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This intuition seems to be  only loosely right. There are many smooth compact CY threefolds with large fundamental groups. For instance $\mathbb{Z}/3\times \mathbb{Z}/3$, $\mathbb{Z}/8\times \mathbb{Z}/8$, are allowed fundamental groups and I am pretty sure that those do not act freely on $S^{3}$.

More to the point - the Calabi-Yau threefolds that have these fundamental groups are explicitly constructed and we have a pretty good idea of the shape of (at least one of) their slag torus fibrations. For instance, in the first case the Calabi-Yau fibers by genus one curves over a rational elliptic surface, and the slag fibration is compatible with the genus one fibration. In the second case the Calabi-Yau fibers by abelian surfaces and again the slag fibration is compatible. So guided by the holomorphic picture you can easily imagine a situation where you group acts freely on the CY, preserves the slag torus fibration, and the induced action on the base of the fibration is *not* free. The only thing you can conclude really is that the action of the group on any fiber sitting over a fixed  point in the base is free. This is possible to arrange on a torus by taking action by translations.

So, even if your fundamental group happens to admit some free action on $S^{3}$, this doesn't mean that the action on the base of the slag fibration will be free. And, in general, I don't expect it to be free.

Comment: Tony, thanks a lot for the answer! Would you mind to give a reference for the construction of these manifolds (together with fibrations)? 

Comment: There are many possible constructions of the first one: via toric geometry, via elliptic fibrations, via abelian surface fibrations, etc. The elliptic fibration construction is written for instance in my old paper <a href="http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0410055">http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0410055</a>. You can see there that the group acts freely on the total space but acts with fixed points on the base of the elliptic fibration. 

The second Calabi-Yau  was originally constructed by Gross-Popescu as a pencil of abelian surfaces with polarizations $(1,8)$. 

Comment: Tony thanks a lot for all these references!

Comment: There is a very nice and detailed description of this CY in the
Gross-Pavanelli paper http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0512182. If you have
not seen those, you may also want to take a look at this paper
http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0609728 by Borisov-Hua, and the paper
http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0609728 of Bouchard-Donagi.
